# ¿Cuál sería el término adecuado en español para decir "networking"?

Tags: traducción, inglés

¿Cuál es la mejor manera de traducir al español el término *Networking*?

Es para el título de un libro que originalmente se titula "Networking for dummies".

Comment: Pusé el libro pero no la traducción de dummies. Eso cabe a Ud.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que me extraña es que estés buscando la traducción de ese título, pues el libro ya fue adaptado y editado en castellano en el año 2018, como "***Networking para dummies***":
[image]

De hecho, no se traduce **networking** por una sola palabra: en varias partes del libro, la define con frases completas, pero no con una expresión única.

> red de contactos

> El networking debe tomarse como una actividad, ya que es experimental, es decir, evoca a la acción, y sugiere un camino con varias etapas clave. El networking puede verse como el proceso de creación de redes que cuenta con fases que van desde la ejecución y el seguimiento hasta la gestión de la red y de cada uno de sus integrantes.

> El networking es una actividad que puede tener un inicio, pero, por sus características, no tiene un final, sino que funciona como ciclos de retroalimentación; es decir, cada cierto tiempo tomamos los resultados obtenidos, los evaluamos y, a partir de ahí, con esta nueva información, contactos y resultados de las acciones aplicadas, volvemos al sistema o red y lo reactivamos.

Por eso creo que se ha usado la palabra en inglés: para no tener que hacer una perífrasis.

Answer (score 0):

"Networking" puede ser aplicado a distintas areas, o bien se refiere a como funcionan las capas en red como un concepto (conexión en red, conectividad) o bien a relaciones sociales o comerciales. Con "dummies" sugiere que se refiere a un guía que es un "getting started" es decir una introduccion paso a paso de lo simple a lo más técnico para gente que no sabe del tema o para la que tiene dudas sobre eso, explicando conceptos, jergas, convenciones, dando consejos sobre que aspectos se debe evaluar antes de profundizar, ejemplos prácticos para desarrollar habilidades, trucos e/o imágenes acerca de la configuración técnica, prácticas recomendadas para implementar un determinado protocolo, etc para hacer que, como en este caso, la red funcione o para que esté operativa.

Puede incluir diagramas explicativos, comandos, procedimientos a seguir de como p.ej. conectar los dispositivos, etc p.ej:

- Configuración de redes para principiantes.
- Introducción a redes.
- Guía práctica de admistración de redes.
- Cómo montar tu red desde cero.

Depende del contexto.

El típico formato es:

> Chapter 1: Introduction / Chapter 2: The Nuts and Bolts of / Chapter 3: Implementing / Chapter 4: Settings / Chapter 5: Tricks and Tips / Chapter 6: Tools / Chapter 7: Troubleshootings / etc

Answer (score 0):

[image: Networking for Dummies]

Spanish translation of 'networking'
Word Frequency
networking
[ˈnetwɜːkɪŋ]
NOUN
(Computing) **conexión f de redes**

[Collins Dictionary _ English > Spanish](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-spanish/networking)

[conexión de red(es) en Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conexi%C3%B3n_de_red#:%7E:text=Una%20conexi%C3%B3n%20de%20red%20designa,y%20una%20red%20inform%C3%A1tica.)

Una conexión de red designa la conexión entre un equipo informático (en el sentido ETD, es decir, un ordenador, una impresora, etc.) y una red informática.

Se puede interpretar en varios niveles correspondientes a las capas bajas del modelo OSI:

Puede tratarse de una conexión física (véase Capa física): el equipo considerado está en interacción eléctrica (mediante un cable de red coaxial o de par trenzado) o electromagnética (ondas de radio, infrarrojas, etc.) con los demás equipos de la red.

Puede tratarse de una conexión lógica en el sentido de que los equipos conectados disponen del conjunto de protocolos de red necesario para, una vez activados, comunicarse entre sí. Por ejemplo, el equipo considerado tiene acceso a la red local, y, al activar protocolos superiores, puede conectarse a una red mayor, como Internet (véase Conexión a Internet).